# Markup for turning URLs and Tags into anchors

Tags: javascript, php, regex, hyperlink

How do I turn some links like this

`http://someaddr.ess/linked [URL NAME]`

into

`<a href="http://someaddr.ess/linked">URL NAME</a>`

I'm looking for solution in PHP or jQuery.

**I didn't find a solution particularly for this in stackoverflow. If you already know some answers, please link to it.*

Comment: StackOverflow isn't for providing you with complete solutions but rather helping you with specific problems on the way to your own solution. Thats why you didn't find anything when searching. What you should look at however is regular expressions which would let you write this yourself quite easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$a =  'http://someaddr.ess/linked [URL NAME]';
echo preg_replace('~(https?://\S+)\s*\[([^\]]+)\]~', '<a href="$1">$2</a>', $a);
//=> <a href="http://someaddr.ess/linked">URL NAME</a>
```

Comment: +1 for you @anubhava...nice and simple answer ratherthan me

Comment: Thanks, +1 for your answer since that also works fine with some extra code.

Comment: Thank you, Anubhaba. You're helpful as always. :)
Your code works right away.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this,

```
<?php
    $input ="http://someaddr.ess/linked [URL NAME]";
    $input =str_replace("]", "", $input);
    list($url, $URLTEXT) =explode("[", $input);

    $URL = preg_replace('!(http|ftp|scp)(s)?:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9.?&_/]+!', "<a href=\"\\0\">".$URLTEXT."</a>",$url);     

    echo $URL;
 ?>
```

Comment: Thanks. but it turns the whole string into link. But still thanks for providing me with the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
$str = "http://someaddr.ess/linked [URL NAME]";
$new_arr = explode(' ',$str);

preg_match_all('/\[([A-Za-z]+?)\]/', $str, $text);
echo "<a href='".$new_arr[0]."'>".$text[0]."</a>";
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Gautam. But your code returns an array rather than a string. I may have to tinker with it a little. :)

Comment: See my edit..Hope it will do that

Comment: @Gautam3164 Just to let you know that yours still shows the link as `Array`